# Raspberry boot Радужный квадрат

Tags: raspberry-pi

Добрый день! 
При старте raspberry pi загорается разноцветный квадрат, который указывает что тест GPU пройден, как его скрыть при загрузке?
Я его раньше отключал и это было просто. Сейчас же не могу найти как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, в конце файла /boot/config.txt
Я написал disable_splash =1, а нужно было disable_splash=1. Проблема была в пробеле.